# grunt configurable variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, yeoman

I am using grunt, and I added a parameters to the config:

```
grunt.initConfig({
        // configurable paths
        yeoman: {
            app: 'app',
            dist: 'dist',
            assetsRoot: [
                '../',
                '../a/b/c/',
                '../d/d/s/'
        },
        .
        .
        .
```

Later I used those variable. for example:

```
        clean: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    dot: true,
                    src: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*', // --> dist/*
                        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*' // --> !dist/*
                    ]
                }]
            },
            server: '.tmp'
        },
```

But then I wanted to use the assetsRoot parameter which is an array and not a string. But if I do:

```
        connect: {
            server: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    base: [
                        './',
                        '.tmp'
                    ].concat('<%= yeoman.assetsRoot %>')
                }
            },
        }
```

But this concats a string to the array instead of combining the arrays!
I get:

```
connect.server.options.base = ['./', '.tmp', '[ "../", "../a/b/c/", "../d/d/s/"]']
```

instead of:

```
connect.server.options.base = ['./', '.tmp', '../', '../a/b/c/', '../d/d/s/']
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure but could you give a try with .concat('<% yeoman.assetsRoot %>')?

Answer (score 0):

You're outputting your `assetRoot` array wrapped in single quotes, so yes, it's a string. The compiled output will look like this:

```
[1, 2].concat('[3, 4]')
```

Replace `'<%= yeoman.assetsRoot %>'` with `<%= yeoman.assetsRoot %>` so that you're producing an array.

Comment: But then I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`